# Java map entry string casting issue

Tags: java, string, casting, maps, comparator

I'm making a custom irritator to use in a SortedMap with keys being strings and the values being a count of how many times that string has been read. 
When I run it, I get this error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
    at comp2402a1.Part8$1.compare(Part8.java:21)`

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this casting error. Any help and insight anyone could provide would be really appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
//Custom comparator
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> mapCompare = new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(){ 
  @Override
  public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
    if (o1.getValue()-o2.getValue() != 0){
      return o1.getValue()-o2.getValue(); 
    } else {
      return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()); 
    }
  }
};

//Read lines into a HashMap & count instance #s 
HashMap<String, Integer> hMap = new HashMap(); 
for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
  if (hMap.get(line)==null) {
    hMap.put(line,1); 
    w.println("1");
  } else {
    hMap.put(line, hMap.get(line)+1);
  }
}

//Put objects into sorted map w/custom sort and output
SortedMap<String, Integer> sMap = new TreeMap(mapCompare); 
sMap.putAll(hMap);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : sMap.entrySet()){
  w.println(e.getKey()); 
}
```

}

Comment: Which line is the error at?

Comment: You can't create a `TreeMap<String, Integer>` with a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`. It's expecting a `Comparator<String>`. You could have caught the error at `new TreeMap<>(mapCompare)` if you weren't using raw types.

Comment: Do you actually need the map for lookup, or do you just need an ordered sequence of key/value pairs?

Comment: @shmosel I needed the map for lookup, and the error is at my comparator declaration, line 3

Answer (score 0):

The error was appearing because I was creating a comparator of type `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` instead of `Comparator<String>`.

I fixed it by first creating calling Map.entrySet() on my HashMap, putting that into a list, sorting it, then basing my SortedMap off of that.

Comment: I'm curious how you based your map off of the list. Can you share your code?